# gstreamer side by side video streaming from 2 easycap devices

Tags: raspberry-pi, video-streaming, gstreamer

I'm trying to stream video from 2 easycap devices simultaneously side by side from my raspberry pi 2.

I did a small test and both easycap devices can be streamed simultaneously when i run them as two separate processes:

Command to stream from EasyCap 1:

```
/usr/bin/gst-launch-1.0 --gst-debug=GST_CAPS:4  -vvv v4l2src device=/dev/video0 norm=NTSC ! videoconvert ! omxh264enc target-bitrate=1000000 control-rate=variable-skip-frames ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! gdppay ! tcpserversink host=192.168.1.38 port=5000
```

command to stream from EasyCap 2:

```
/usr/bin/gst-launch-1.0 --gst-debug=GST_CAPS:4  -vvv v4l2src device=/dev/video1 norm=NTSC ! videoconvert ! omxh264enc target-bitrate=1000000 control-rate=variable-skip-frames ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! gdppay ! tcpserversink host=192.168.1.38 port=5001
```

Both processes are running fine, i can see them with top:

```
2859 pi        20   0  170m  14m 9940 S  29.1  1.7   0:01.67 gst-launch-1.0
2847 pi        20   0  170m  14m 9.8m S  28.8  1.7   0:02.51 gst-launch-1.0
```

and i can connect and see stream from EasyCap 1 on port 5000 as well as stream from EasyCap 2 on port 5001.

I can also stream both easycaps combined with "videotestsrc". Like this for easycap1

```
/usr/bin/gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 norm=NTSC ! videoscale ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=640,height=480 ! videobox border-alpha=0 ! videomixer name=mix ! videoconvert ! omxh264enc ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! gdppay ! tcpserversink host=192.168.1.38 port=5000 sync=false videotestsrc pattern=1 ! videoscale ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=640,height=480 ! videobox left=-640 ! mix.
```

OR like this for easycap2

```
/usr/bin/gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video1 norm=NTSC ! videoscale ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=640,height=480 ! videobox border-alpha=0 ! videomixer name=mix ! videoconvert ! omxh264enc ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! gdppay ! tcpserversink host=192.168.1.38 port=5000 sync=false videotestsrc pattern=1 ! videoscale ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=640,height=480 ! videobox left=-640 ! mix.
```

However if I try to combine two easycaps into one stream it fails. Here is the command I use:

```
/usr/bin/gst-launch-1.0 --gst-debug=GST_CAPS:4 -vvv v4l2src device=/dev/video1 norm=NTSC ! videoscale ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=640,height=480 ! videobox border-alpha=0 ! videomixer name=mix ! videoconvert ! omxh264enc ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! gdppay ! tcpserversink host=192.168.1.38 port=5000 sync=false v4l2src device=/dev/video0 norm=NTSC ! videoscale ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=640,height=480 ! videobox left=-640 ! mix.
```

here is the output

```
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)YUY2, framerate=(fraction)30000/1001, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)mixed, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1  
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)YUY2, framerate=(fraction)30000/1001, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)mixed, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1  
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoScale:videoscale1.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, framerate=(fraction)30000/1001, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)mixed, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, format=(string)YUY2  
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoScale:videoscale0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, framerate=(fraction)30000/1001, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)mixed, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, format=(string)YUY2 
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoConvert:videoconvert2.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, framerate=(fraction)30000/1001, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)mixed, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, format=(string)YUY2  
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoConvert:videoconvert0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, framerate=(fraction)30000/1001, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)mixed, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, format=(string)YUY2  
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter1.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, framerate=(fraction)30000/1001, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)mixed, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, format=(string)YUY2  
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, framerate=(fraction)30000/1001, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)mixed, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, format=(string)YUY2  
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoBox:videobox1.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, framerate=(fraction)30000/1001, width=(int)1280, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)mixed, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, format=(string)YUY2  
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoBox:videobox0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, framerate=(fraction)30000/1001, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)mixed, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, format=(string)YUY2  
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoMixer2:mix.GstVideoMixer2Pad:sink_0: caps = video/x-raw, framerate=(fraction)30000/1001, width=(int)1280, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)mixed, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, format=(string)YUY2  
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoMixer2:mix.GstVideoMixer2Pad:sink_0: caps = video/x-raw, framerate=(fraction)30000/1001, width=(int)1280, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)mixed, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, format=(string)YUY2  
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoBox:videobox1.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, framerate=(fraction)30000/1001, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)mixed, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, format=(string)YUY2  
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoBox:videobox1.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, framerate=(fraction)30000/1001, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)mixed, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, format=(string)YUY2  
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter1.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, framerate=(fraction)30000/1001, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)mixed, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, format=(string)YUY2  
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoConvert:videoconvert2.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, framerate=(fraction)30000/1001, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)mixed, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, format=(string)YUY2  
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoScale:videoscale1.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)YUY2, framerate=(fraction)30000/1001, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, interlace-mode=(string)mixed, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1  
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Internal data flow error.  
Additional debug info:  
gstbasesrc.c(2865): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0  /GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:  
streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)  
Execution ended after 0:00:00.159226895  
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...  
Setting pipeline to READY ...  
Setting pipeline to NULL ...  
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Gstreamer version is

```
/usr/bin/gst-launch-1.0 --version
gst-launch-1.0 version 1.2.4
GStreamer 1.2.4
```

Appreciate any help

Comment: Your question is almost unreadable... you should format it in a better way

Comment: Fixed. Sorry about that

Comment: This should be able to be debugged from a GST_DEBUG=6 log. Can you try with a recent version? 1.4 or maybe 1.5.90+ ? If this still persists please file a bug in gstreamer's bugzilla.